# How to detect element with DOM JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, background

I want to detect an element and change the backgroundColor through JavaScript but am having trouble with it.

I can't check for the element because it is a tag+class + tag+class...

Here's my code :

```
var one = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var two = document.getElementsByClassName("red");
var three = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var four = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
one.two three.four.style.backgroundColor ="#00c497";
```

The format is "div.red h2.title".

How can I correctly detect an element using DOM JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for this:

```js
document.querySelector("div.red h2.title").style.backgroundColor = "#00c497";
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Don't Touch</h2>  
</div>
<div class="red">
  <h2>Don't Touch</h2>
  <h2 class="title">Change</h2>
</div>
```